# sqlite3: group by x having count(y > N)

Tags: sqlite

I have a table `users` with this structure:

```
id | user     | offset 
0  | alvin    | -1     
1  | alvin    | -2
2  | alvin    |  5
3  | alvin    |  6
4  | simon    | -5
5  | simon    | -4
6  | theodore | -1
7  | theodore |  1
```

I want a query that returns the distinct usernames which have at least 1 positive entry AND at least 1 negative entry in `offset`.  In this example, the query would return "alvin" and "theodore" but not "simon".

I've looked at a number of other posts related to `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `COUNT()`, and combinations thereof, but none of them seem to address this idea of counting the number of true returns from a conditional statement.   In particular, I think I'm misunderstanding how to incorporate aggregate functions like `count()` into the `WHERE` clause (or if that's even possible). When I try something like:

```
SELECT user FROM users WHERE count(offset > 0) > 0;
```

I get an error: `misuse of aggregate function count()`

(I know that statement doesn't full specify the query I want - it's meant more as an indication of how I've been trying to approach the problem.)

I'm coming from a Python/Pandas mindset here, and it may just be that this approach doesn't translate well to SQL.

Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT user
FROM users
WHERE offset > 0
UNION
SELECT user
FROM users
WHERE offset < 0;
```

It is actually possible to use aggregation functions.
However, COUNT() counts *rows*; to count something else, it is a better idea to use a boolean expression (returning 0 or 1), and SUM() that:

```
SELECT user
FROM users
GROUP BY user
HAVING SUM(offset < 0) > 0
   AND SUM(offset > 0) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked beautifully!  Re: your second solution, I needed to put `HAVING` after `GROUP BY` though, otherwise I got an error.